Ajax Response Html with html download links not working and other issue
I'm absolutely not expert on js and html, following the answers and samples of stackoverflow I found a way to publish on my website a external html source. In the external source there are present some link to download csv files, in the original page the links works correctly in the ajax responce is not possible to download these files.
I have read many posts on a possible solution but I was unable to understand how to apply the proposed solutions.
Another problem is a DIV that I tried to remove through the .remove () instruction without success (always following some posts found).
Div I want to display with download links clientArea
Div I want to remove buttons
Following a part of external html, the single html DIV in my webpage and the script i'm using (i removed the instruction .remove())
Thanks..
I add some info cause the comments received..
First One
Calling each() on an id selector is ringing alarm bells - you should only ever have 1 element in the DOM with any given id value. If you have multiple, use a class
If the comment is about to change id in class.. the external source is not editable.. although I'm not sure I understood correctly
Second One
Also, I'm assuming those ** are to emphasise the relevant parts in your question, and not actually in the code. I'd suggest removing them either way, as they are ambiguous as to being a problem in themselves.
The ** symbols were inserted to transform the text into bold.. I didn't know that they didn't work in the code block.. I remove them..
Third one
Can you give us an example, of what exactly this external source contains? And when you inspect the newly inserted links using your browser dev tools - is there anything significantly different about them, compared to the ones that were already contained in the document to begin with?
The section of the html page shown is exactly the copy and paste of the external source, I just removed irrelevant html..
Apparently there is no difference. The list of download links (I only listed one) is dynamically generated and allocated in a table. Initially it was not managed by my html page, but by adding the reference to the js script also used by the original one the table was populated with the following links.
<a href='/DataLogs?Path=/DataLogs/Mer.csv&amp;Action=DOWNLOAD '>Mer.csv</a>

The html frame shown on my DIV Datalog page is identical to that of the external page.
HTML
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="clientArea">

    <div id="titleArea">
    <h1>Log di dati</h1>
      <div class="updatable Title_Area_Selectbox" id="filebrowser_selectbox">

      </div>
      <div id="buttons">
      <span id="dynamic_link">
      <a class="Link_ReloadIcon" href="../ReloadSite.mwsl">
      <img height="13" title="Aggiorna" alt="Refresh" src="../Images/ICO_WEB_refresh.gif">
      </a>
      </span>
      <a class='PrinterIcon_Active' href='../Portal/Print.mwsl?PriNav=DataLogs' target=_blank>&nbsp;
      <img title="Stampa" style="PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px; HEIGHT: 13px" height="13" alt=Print src="../Images/ICO_WEB_Drucken.gif">
      </a>
      </div>

  </div>
    <div id="separatorLine3"></div>
      <table id="DataLogsError"><tr><td class="Error_Message"></td></tr></table>
      <div class="updatable" id="FilebrowserTable">
      <table class="ContentTable">
      <tr>
        <td id="File_Name" class="ContentTableField_1">Nome</td>
        <td id="File_Size" class="ContentTableField_1">Dimensione</td>
        <td id="File_Dates" class="ContentTableField_1">Modificato il</td>
        <td id="File_Status" class="ContentTableField_1">Attivo</td>
        <td id="File_Delete" class="ContentTableField_1">Cancella</td>
        <td class="Filebrowser_No_Sort_Header"><span class="nobr">Recupera e cancella</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td class='ContentTableField'><a href='/DataLogs?Path=/DataLogs/Mer.csv&amp;Action=DOWNLOAD'>Mer.csv</a>
    </td>
    <td class="ContentTableField_Filesize"><span class="nobr">5,08 KB</span></td>
    <td class="ContentTableField"><span class="nobr">18:10:00   26.06.2024</span></td>
    <td class="ContentTableField">No</td>

...
  </body>
</html>

IN MY WEBPAGE
<Div id="DataLog"></Div>

SCRIPT IN MY WEBPAGE
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(function() {
              $.ajax({
                url:"/Portal/Portal.mwsl?PriNav=DataLogs",
                type:"GET",
                dataType:'html',
                success:function(data) {
                  var out = "";
                  $(data).find("#clientArea").each(function(loop, item){out += $(item).html();});
                  data = out;
                  alert(data);
                 $("#DataLog").html(data);
              }                  
            })
        });
        });
    </script>


Calling each() on an id selector is ringing alarm bells - you should only ever have 1 element in the DOM with any given id value. If you have multiple, use a class

Also, I'm assuming those ** are to emphasise the relevant parts in your question, and not actually in the code. I'd suggest removing them either way, as they are ambiguous as to being a problem in themselves.

Can you give us an example, of what exactly this external source contains? And when you inspect the newly inserted links using your browser dev tools - is there anything significantly different about them, compared to the ones that were already contained in the document to begin with?
